# What are "Facebook App User ID" and "Facebook Page User ID"?

Tags: facebook-ads

Facebook seems to hide away the meaning of those terms when creating Audiences for ads.

I just want to know - do those terms refer to apps/pages' numerical IDs or to users' numerical IDs (like [4](https://www.facebook.com/4) for Mark Zuckerberg)? And if it's the latter, what's the difference between the two terms?

The closest Facebook agrees to reveal is https://www.facebook.com/business/help/606443329504150 which mentions only the first term and even then doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

A `Page User ID` is a name for a page [a custom Username for my Page or profile](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=1536692743024228). It is visible to the public.

An `App User ID` is a code for a particular browser to protect FB users’ anonymity but to allow advertisers to target specific audiences. [Details](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-and-privacy/relevant-ads-that-protect-your-privacy/457827624267125).

Comment: 1) So do you claim it's meant to target people who liked a certain page, for example people who liked https://www.facebook.com/20531316728? Because some think it's a secret way to target direct users.
2) Your link about apps didn't mention apps. If what you say about 1) is right, it seems logical it's simply meant to target people who used a certain app.

Comment: 1) It=Facebook App User ID. The link relates to Facebook Exchange while I refer to Custom Audiences.